# How to interpret the relationship status question in a UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk

In a UK visa application, what does the option 'unmarried partner' signify? Should someone who has never been married but is in a stable, long term relationship answer 'single' or 'unmarried partner'?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: Sorry, in connection with a UK Visit visa application. We consider our relationship to be long term therefore we are 'partners', but I've never come across the term 'unmarried partner' before.

Comment: I take that to apply to your situation. When we say partner in this context it generally means unmarried partner and the visa form is trying to be unambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Unmarried partner" signifies someone who is in a stable, long-term relationship (or partnership) but is not legally married.  It would appear therefore to apply to you.

Comment: https://www.lawfirmuk.net/unmarriedpartner_e

Comment: Information I've found on the web provides a legal definition for the term 'unmarried partner'.

Comment: According to the Immigration Rules and the EEA regulations, the term unmarried partner relationship is be defined as:
"Two persons living together in a relationship akin to marriage for at least two years".
This definition does not include casual acquaintances or any unstable relationship in which neither of the parties have any long term intentions to live together. The partnership would have to be proven by way of household bills and bank statements and anything else that can help prove cohabitation covering the relevant period.